# What is the common term for "receiving an email but unable to give an immediate reply"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

**Question:** Is there a term for a reply that confirms the original email's receipt, but states the need of more time before replying again substantively?

I've heard 'Holding Replies/Responses', but is this a universal term? Is there a better one?

Comment: Yes, "holding response" is generally understood. In fact I don't think I've ever heard any other term.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I strongly suspect that Canada 51 asked his question because he was puzzled when a user explained he was using ["holding reply"](http://ultimatejargonbuster.com/holdingreply.html) incorrectly. https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/3750/3114

Comment: Ah. It's certainly unusual to **request** a holding response! One can be sent such a reply ("Sorry, no time at the moment: I'll send an answer next week"), but one would normally only request an ***acknowledgment:*** you don't really **want** a holding response.

Comment: The premise of this question is severely wrong, there is no common term. Let alone a 'universal one'. Proof: "holding reply" only has 8240 Google hits and "holding replies" only 4850. That's fewer than archaisms like "escheat" and "chattel". The correct answer is "There is no common term, but here's one very rarely-used term which 99.9% of people have never heard of". Telling the OP otherwise is a severe disservice to him, he's [demanding ( why other people (native English speakers) won't send him "Holding Replies"](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/3750)

Comment: @smci I am user3114, and if you had looked, the question linked in my comment is exactly the same one you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following, **holding reply**, is an accepted and established term. It describes an email that is sent to explain or justify a delay in a work environment.

[*The Independent*](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/a-guide-to-email-etiquette-427292.html) says

> As with letters, it is polite to reply to e-mails promptly. **A few words suffice as a holding reply** (and reassure the sender that the e-mail has been received) until a longer reply can be composed.

It would, therefore, be inappropriate to use the term in a message such as this:

> Despite requesting, in one of my first emails to you, **that you email me Holding Replies** to assure me that you received my initial email while I await your second reply,... [source](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/how-to-politely-tell-someone-that-you-shouldnt-need-to-chase-for-replies-that-i)

Note that the expression ***holding reply*** is not a proper noun it, therefore, does not require capital letters. The excuse or apology you write in an email that informs the recipient that you will send a more detailed reply at a later date is called a holding reply, *but you do not ask for* “holding replies”, which is what `that you email me Holding Replies` is really saying.

Here is another [example](https://www.learning.ox.ac.uk/media/global/wwwadminoxacuk/localsites/oxfordlearninginstitute/documents/pdg/managingyourself/4_email_-_writing_emails.pdf) of how to use the term correctly. [emphasis mine]

> **Be a Good Correspondent**
>
> Make sure that you go through your inbox regularly and respond as appropriate. This is a simple act of courtesy and will also serve to encourage others to reply to your emails in a timely manner. If a detailed response is required to an email, and you don't have the time to pull together the information straight away, *send a* ***holding reply*** *saying that you have received the message, and indicating when you will respond fully*

@Andrew Leach in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409619/is-there-a-term-for-a-reply-that-confirms-the-original-emails-receipt-but-stat#comment976758_409619) explains it better

> It's certainly unusual to **request** a holding response! One can be sent such a reply ("Sorry, no time at the moment: I'll send an answer next week"), but one would normally only request an ***acknowledgment***: you don't really **want** a holding response

Comment: No it's not an "accepted and established" term. *"holding reply"* only has 8240 Google hits and *"holding replies"* only 4850. That's fewer than archaisms like "escheat" and "chattel". Even the premise of this question is wrong, in wrongly assuming there is a common term - there simply isn't. The correct answer is "There is no common term, but here's one very rarely-used term which 99.9% of people have never heard of". Telling the OP otherwise is a severe disservice to him, he's demanding why other people (native English speakers) won't send him "Holding Replies".

Comment: @smci the reason why "holding reply" has fewer hits than "escheat" (14th c)  and "chattel" (14th c) is because it's been around a lot less. Chattel is also a surname, and both terms are still used in real estate and legal contracts. Here is the [proof](https://www.google.com/search?q=escheat&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz9-Gw6u7XAhWIvBoKHXHOBYQ4WhD8BQgLKAI&biw=1285&bih=608): About 1,050 results for *escheat* as reported by Google *news*, check the dates. E.g 13 July 2017 https://www.law360.com/articles/943607/mortgage-servicers-should-review-escheat-compliance

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard the term "holding response." It may be a new phrase.

I would probably describe it as "acknowledging receipt." That does not imply a substantive response.